# ActionScript - Masking Programmatically Drawn Graphics?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, process, mask

suppose i have a large, static, programmatically drawn vector graphic that extends well beyond the stage.

is it recommended to mask the graphic with the stage dimensions?  does the VM still draw the portion that is not on the stage?

does masking half of a programmatically drawn graphic reduce the drawing process by half?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it still draws it, even if it's beyond the stage. Performance-wise, the best thing to use is scrollRect, where your create a rectangle and tell is only to draw anything within that rectangle on screen. It's way better performance-wise than a mask too. http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/11/understanding_d.html

Comment: do you have any docs or benchmarks that proves this? i'd love to see that!

Comment: it comes straight from adobe and their Flash player engineers - it's how it's designed. Masks will let you selectively show content, but it will still render the whole object and all things associated with it - scrollRect only renders what's in your rectangle. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e35zephyr_serranozephyr.html

Comment: and this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001352.html